# How to simultaneously pass parameters internally and make external url call on form submit?

Tags: forms

I'm using Drupal 7.15, and have setup a simple form with a textfield, textarea, and file fields.

This is the code I use in `upload($form, &$from_state)`.

```
// Return textfield, textarea, file upload 
$form['data'] = simple_form($form, $form_state);

// Call internal function
$form['redirect_uri'] = array(
  '#type' => 'hidden',
  '#value' => url('upload/completed/' . $asset, array('absolute' => TRUE)),
);

// Submit form
$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#description' => t('Upload your file'),
  '#value' => t('Upload'),
  // '#submit' => array('upload_completed),
);

// pass params to this other external url via get
$form['#action'] = $upload_url;
```

Upon submit, the form is submitted to `$form['action']`; then the user is redirected to  `$form['redirect_uri']`.

This is the code for `upload_completed($form, &$form_state, $asset)`.

```
 // Stored values and input are blank because $form is not being passed
 $form_state['stored_values'] = $form['input'];

 // I do some processing of the $form_state['stored_values'] here

 // then I forward control to another url, and that's it. 
 drupal_goto($some_url);
```

I'm unable to process any of the form data in upload_completed(), because it's empty. How can I pass the data in the form created in upload() and call the #action url simultaneously? The redirect passes via GET, so Sessions are a possibility. When I use the callback:

```
 $form['submit'] { ... '#submit' => array(callback) ... }
```

only the $form['action'] url gets called, not the #submit function. Since I'm able to pass data by reference, I really need to have that function called. Thanks in advance!

P.S. Here's how the redirect, upload_completed is called in hook_menu:

```
 $items['upload/completed/%'] = array(
  'title' => 'Upload asset',
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('upload_completed', 3),
  'description' => 'Nothing left to do, file uploaded.',
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  'visible' => FALSE,
  'file' => 'file.asset.inc',
 );
```

Comment: May you show the code you are using? `$form['submit']['#value']` is the label that is shown for the button.

Comment: I made edits to initial question, and added what I thought were relevant parts. Thanks for your interest! In the back of my head, sounds like I need to make some AJAX calls as well, but not sure.

Comment: I have a last question; then, I should be able to give you a complete answer. I assume the files are uploaded to the external server, which then redirects the user to the URL passed in `$form['redirect_uri']`. What data do you need in `upload_completed()`? Do you need the value entered for the form fields?

Comment: I do need the values entered for the form fields in upload_completed(). Right now, var_dump of $form within that function returns empty array. And yes, the files are uploaded to an external server (this part works), but I still have some additional processing that I'd like to have done after it redirects. Thanks!